# Using letters as numeric keypad

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

My keyboard doesn't have a numeric keypad. However, it's very useful and, sometimes, I would like to use it. I'm looking for some good way to map my letters to number when using some modification key. For example:

- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> = 1
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> = 2
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> = 3
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd> = 4
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> = 5
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>o</kbd> = 6
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>7</kbd> = 7
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> = 8
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> = 9
- <kbd>ModKey</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> = 0

Given I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNOME 3.36.8), I want (1) a good key combination with little chance of overriding other system shortcuts (I thought about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>, but I don't know), and (2) a way to do this.

Comment: Do you need it in a shell like bash, or do you want this behavior persistent on Desktop applications as well? If you need it for the entire environment and not only for a bash shell, what is your Distro / Desktop?

Comment: @aviro I forgot to add the details of my system, I'm sorry. I just edited the question. And yes, I want it available system-wide, just like Compose keys.